# Помогите составить SQL запрос из 3 таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Есть три таблицы
Salesperson

```
ID  Name    Age Salary
1   Tom     61  140000
2   Michael 34  44000
5   Chris   34  40000
7   Dan     41  52000
8   Ken     57  115000
11  Joe     38  38000
```

Customer

```
ID   Name          City    Industry Type
4   IVM            New York     J
6   Panosong       Florida      J
7   Seamens        Chicago      B
9   Nowkia         Houston      B
```

Orders

```
Number  order_date  cust_id salesperson_id  Amount
10        8/2/96      4           2         540
20        1/30/99     4           8         1800
30        7/14/95     9           1         460
40        1/29/98     7           2         2400
50        2/3/98      6           7         600
60        3/2/98      6           7         720
70        5/6/98      9           7         150
```

Необходимо вывести имена всех продавцов, не имеющих заказы от Seamens
Как нужно объединять таблицы, с помощью inner join?

Comment: а так пробовали? `WHERE customer.Name <> 'Seamens';`

Comment: не то, возможно я не правильно запрос составляю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Salesperson.Name 
FROM Orders
JOIN Customer ON Orders.cust_id = Customer.ID
JOIN Salesperson ON Orders.salesperson_id = Salesperson.ID
WHERE Customer.Name != 'Seamens'
GROUP BY Orders.salesperson_id
```

Comment: Тут же выбираются все продавцы, у которых есть заказы от всех кроме сименса. А нужны все у кого нет заказов от сименса. Это немножко разные условия

Comment: Да, понял, сейчас исправлю. Недавно была похожая задача

Comment: Не надо исправлять. Автор посчитал ответ правильным. Видимо условие описанное автором не корректно.

Comment: @Okdel Да странно, у меня сейчас неправильно, попадают в список продавцы, которые продали что-то, в том числе и сименсу, если были продажи другим.

Answer (score 1):

Используй EXISTS

```
SELECT
  s.name
FROM
  Salesperson s
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        Orders o,
        Customer c
      WHERE
        o.salesperson_id = s.id AND
        c.id = o.cust_id AND
        c.name = 'Seamens'
    )
```